# как сделать проигрывание видео по скроллу? (это вроде называется lottie анимацией)

Tags: javascript, html, css

мне нужно чтобы на сайте когда доходишь до определенного блока начинало проигрываться видео по скроллу? как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Повесить обработчик события, на отлеживания события скролла. Когда пользователь проскролит N px от начала страницы, запускать функцию которая отвечает за проигрывание видео.

Comment: нет, нужно чтобы именно само видео покадрово от скрола проигрывалось

Comment: идея та же. На скролл вешать событие, потом перематывать на нужный кадр, в видео и запускать видео... Если там не видео, а какая то раскадровка, то лучше подключите пример к вопросу.