# как сделать чтобы видео покадрово проигрывалась по скролу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы текущее время видео зависело от текущего местоположения скролла?
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при скролле, текущее время видео менялось (кадр), а само время должно зависеть от положения ползунка в определённом месте на странице. Как такое можно реализовать?

Текущее время можно менять с помощью videoElement.currentTime, но как реализовать то, что описано выше?

Comment: по шагам - разбиваем видео на кадры(утилита FFMPEG) после этого соединяем все эти кадры в один ролик на javascript в один то есть другими словами подменяем  src в теге img - после того как это получилось меняем кадры в зависимости от количества прокрученых пикселей

Comment: Где-то я видел этот вопрос... И текст очень подозрительно похож на тот, который писал я... Хмм...

Comment: @ΝNL993 [оно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483089/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d1%83-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-lottie-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5)?

Comment: @eccs0103 да я уже и сам нашёл :) у меня там черновик сохранился под ответ. Странно правда что правки нет... Даже в истории правок.

Comment: я загрузил папку в zip и в облако mail.ru, посмотрите так надо ? https://cloud.mail.ru/public/srET/peKRkqxGF

Comment: а как сделать чтобы оно начинало проигрываться только когда я дошел до этого блока. вот допустим до этого блока было расстояние 700vh

Comment: @MonkeyMutant можете подсказать еще как сделать чтобы оно медленнее скролилось?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant и еще как сделать чтобы оно начало проигрываться именно когда доскролишь до этого блока, допустим до этого блока было 700vh других.

Comment: как понять медленее ? выже сами скролите

Comment: вот так можно скроллить медленее... опять архив в облаке mail.ru: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/uDjx/CdZQPnt9S

Comment: @MonkeyMutant спасибо, можете еще подсказать как сделать чтобы анимация работала только тогда когда я докручу сайт до нее, допустим перед блоком с этой анимацией было еще 5 размерами по 500vh

Comment: простите - этого я не умею - задайте новый вопрос - в качестве примера предъявите этот код и поясните подробно что вы хотите получить

Comment: @MonkeyMutant понял, а вы может знаете как сделать пустой скрол у блока? Ну типо на экране низ блока дошел до края и уже должен начинаться показываться верх блока который ниже находится, а я хочу чтобы было какое-то расстояние между этим

Comment: Я не уверен что у меня получится но я попробую сделать

Answer (score 1):

#### Шаг 1: Процент полоски.

Чтобы узнать процент полоски есть несколько методов. Лично мне понравился вот этот:

```js
function percentage(content, viewport) {
    return (viewport.scrollTop || content.scrollTop) / ((viewport.scrollHeight || content.scrollHeight) - viewport.clientHeight) * 100;
}
```

...взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028584/12903672).

#### Шаг 2: Процент видео

Процент видео ещё проще:

```js
const video = document.querySelector(`video`);
const percentage = video.currentTime / video.duration;
```

#### Шаг 3: Синхронизация

Чтобы видео с полоской совпали, надо чтобы их процент был тот же. То есть

> процент видео = процент полоски

...а поскольку `процент видео` выяснили что равно `время / длительность`

> время / длительность = процент полоски

...и так как мы контролируем только время видео уравнение на js будет таким:

```js
video.currentTime = Math.floor(percentage(content, viewport)) * video.duration;
```

#### Шаг 4: Слежка за изменениями

Теперь нам надо использовать это уравнение как только пользователь крутит полоску, то есть:

```js
viewport.addEventListener(`scroll`, (event) => {
    function percentage(content, viewport) {
        return (viewport.scrollTop || content.scrollTop) / ((viewport.scrollHeight || content.scrollHeight) - viewport.clientHeight);
    }

    const video = document.querySelector(`video`);
    video.currentTime = Math.floor(percentage(content, viewport)) * video.duration;
});
```

#### Тонкие моменты

Не уверен насколько эффективно покрутить видео покадрово насчет оптимизации. Видео должно скачиваться, может зависать, плюс ещё пользователь может полоской туды сюды делать и вероятно лагать будет.

Comment: Мдам, не слишком ваш способ и любит старые браузеры.

Comment: @ΝNL993 я и сам не люблю старые браузеры)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
document.onscroll = function(){
    video.currentTime = document.body.scrollTop / document.body.scrollHeight * video.duration;
}
```

```html
<video style='position: fixed' id=video src='https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4' width="300" controls></video>
```

Comment: у меня просто видео появляется и все

Comment: Странно, этот код не должен вызывать сомнений, что он работает, но почему-то не читается свойство video.durration из файла. Чуть позже разберусь. Можете даже Вы поисследовать, что для этого не зватает. Если удастся, то в итоге код должен работать.